# In Memory String compression in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, zip, compression, gzip

I have a long string which I'd like to compress within memory to write it into a file later.

Isn't there any lib available to use in Swift (2) that works on both iOS 8 and 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use zlib.  Here is [an example](https://github.com/tidwall/DeflateSwift/blob/master/deflate.swift).